# How do I delete multiple rows with it's Id matching an Id from the http get array I sent to the method? (.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to remove selected rows from a webpage, I already succesfully sent the Id's of the rows I want to delete to the method I want to delete them with. However I can't figure out what to do with those Id's now.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> deleteMultiple(int[] resultatenLijst)
    {
        //List<Resultaat> resultaat = new List<Resultaat>();
        var resultaat = _context.Resultaat.ToList();

        foreach (var resultaatId in resultatenLijst)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("meegegeven resultaatid is: " + resultaatId);
            resultaat = resultaat.Where(r=> r.Id == resultaatId);
            resultList.Add(resultaat);
        }
        _context.Resultaat.RemoveRange(resultList);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Aanpassen));
    }
```

**Error messages:**

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)   ResultatenSysteem   ResultatenSysteem\Controllers\ResultatenController.cs   278 Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'ResultatenSysteem.Models.Resultaat'   ResultatenSysteem   ResultatenSysteem\Controllers\ResultatenController.cs   279 Active

Comment: There isn't much context here. You need to expand on your question.

Comment: You're right, I've now included the error messages.

Comment: Oh, so the 2 errors are conversion errors. When using Linq, your collections will be IEnumerable and not a List. Your first error there is a list expected. Update this line `resultaat = resultaat.Where(r=> r.Id == resultaatId);` to `resultaat = resultaat.Where(r=> r.Id == resultaatId).ToList();`

Second error, you're trying to add a list to a list. Use Concat, not Add. `resultList = resultList.Concat(resultaat).ToList();`

Comment: The errors are gone, thanks. However it seems that resultList isn't filled with resultaat, it throw an error though. When trying to write every instance of resultaat in resultlist to the console, it doesn't do anything. Also when trying to post the data now it keeps loading, after about 30 seconds give or take it returns to the page specified in return RedirectToAction, without having deleted the selected rows. Do you know what it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way it works for me, however `var resultaat = await _context.Resultaat.FindAsync(0);` might be a dirty way of getting it to work, I wouldn't know.

```
     public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteMultipleRows(int[] resultatenLijst, List<Resultaat> resultList)
    {
        var resultaat = await _context.Resultaat.FindAsync(0);
        foreach (var resultaatId in resultatenLijst)
        {
            resultaat = await _context.Resultaat.FindAsync(resultaatId);
            resultList.Add(resultaat);
        }
        _context.Resultaat.RemoveRange(resultList);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Aanpassen));
    }
```